# Using errorlevel in batch file to add network printer

Tags: batch, script, printing

I'm trying to write a script so people can add a network printer by just typing in it's name.

```
REM Adding network printer 

@echo off
:addprinter
set /p printer="Please enter the name of the printer you wish to add: "
echo.
echo Adding %printer%
echo.


REM Add printer
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\printserver\%printer%
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
        echo.
        echo Printer not recognized
        echo.
goto :addprinter
)
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
        echo.
        echo Printer added
        echo.
    timeout /t 3 > nul
    goto :default
)


:default
```

The problem is that the errorlevel checks don't work, they always return errorlevel 0, even when the printer failed to add.

Anyone who could help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

That means

```
if %errorlevel% 1 (
```

instead of

```
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
```

A batch file is not C++ :)

Comment: Thanks unfortunately I'm getting an error:
0 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @user489000 use `rem @echo off` and you will see where it is failing.

Comment: Doesn't give to much extra info except:

if 0 0 (

at the end, then it quits